# Convert wav file to pcap

Tags: audio, audio-streaming

Trying to find a way to covert .wav file to pcap file. I have tried a open source program wav2rtp but the pcap file generated using this program is giving errors when I try to open pcap file in wireshark.

Is there a simpler way to do this file conversion ?

I have .wav & .au formats of the sound file.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can stream audio (wav in in case) via RTP using VLC easily using GUI. [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w6fCxPNay2Y) will help you. Don't forget to change your codec/encoder to wav.